# Adding UIBarButtonItem to UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

How do we add a UIBarButtonItem to a UITabBarController?

```
    leftMenuBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem();
    leftMenuBarButtonItem.image = UIImage(named: "menuIcon");
    leftMenuBarButtonItem.target = self;
    leftMenuBarButtonItem.action = "leftMenuBarButtonItemClicked:";
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(leftMenuBarButtonItem, animated: true);
```

The above code doesn't work. Any thought?

Comment: I mean did you place this in your viewdidload?

Comment: Well, shoot, that's very odd

Comment: oh i see, nevermind, its a tabbar, that's why, so what is it that you are tryign to do? Are you tryign to add this to a view controller in the tabbar?

Comment: as in like a viewcontroller of a specific tab?

Comment: I am trying to add a UIBarButtonItem to the top Left of my UITabBarController @Larcerax

Comment: i see, so here's something to think about, the tabbarcontroller only holds viewcontrollers, so you can't really add anything to the tabbarcontroller since it's not built that way, I mean you can't add navigation items, but you can add navigation itms to the viewcontrollers IN the tabs

Comment: @Larcerax I see. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: If this is meant to be an item for the TABBAR itself then this is your problem and Dama11's answer below will help you, but if you are trying to add a nvigation item to the tabbar on the top left or right, this i the porblem

Comment: BUT wait, JAY, one thing to consider

Comment: If you do want to add a navigation item to the view controllers of the tabbar, you will first need to add a naivgationcontroller to the tabbar item and then root a view controller in the taabbar controller, this will help you tremendously